# how to get focus on the items of a listview toching the screen and moving the finger upper and down withoud untouch it - Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with two columns where the user can compare the productName and proudctQty against the stock. There are loads of products in that list and the user may get confuse checking all of them. So, the idea is to highlight the products and their price by using focus.

Does anyone know if would be possible to implement it in listview like on the virtual keyboard (it  isnot onLongTouch or click)?

Could anyone give a hint about how to do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok like in case of wheelpicker iPhone we can highlight the product just follow these steps

1. implement the list's onscrollchangedlistener .
2. put the list in a relative layout with another view at the centerinparent and fillparent 
   on this view you will display the highlighted item.
3. as the list is scrolled update the content over that view inside the overrided onscroll method.

Comment: thank you @Aashish...that makes sense, but it would not work if the rows fit perfectly in the screen what means that will not have any scrollbar... The effect would be similar to the virtual keyboard, if you swipe you finger among the keys, they are highlighted(zoomed).....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a View Holder Pattern. You can find more information on Google.

Simply create a class called `AdapterViewHolder`, declare properties, the `Views` on each row.

For example:

```
public class AdapterViewHolder
{

    ImageView myImageView;

    TextView myTextView;

    ...

}
```

In constructor pass your values to set to the `views`, initialize your `views` and set your values like:

```
public AdapterViewHolder(String param, Drawable imageDrawable){

// set values to views

}
```

In the adapter in `getView` method:

```
if convertView == null 

//then create your layout and holder class, set your holder to your layout by view.setTag method, prepare your view and return it

else

//get your layout tag by view.getTag(), cast it to AdapterViewHolder and update your views and values of them as you like and then return updated view.
```

For more info search for ViewHolder Pattern in android listviews.